# Sorting in Result Set with Paging SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
                  SELECT F.Id,   
                       F.FolderNo,
                       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  F.Id) AS RN  
                INTO #Results4                                  
                FROM   cm.pfmfolder F WITH(nolock)   


  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #Results4  
   WHERE RN BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1  

   DROP TABLE #Results4
```

Here the records are displaying as per the startIndex specified and PageSize, But when it's went to next page records are not sorted with FolderNo, is there any way that i can sort and do paging for this query

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

```
order by FolderNo
```

Here is the example: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cce99/6)

Comment: but when i go to the second page the folder no ascending order is not being continued.

Comment: You could change the @PageIndex to 2 to check the result. I could see it's still ordered by FolderNo. Anything I misunderstood?